# Are type libraries (.tlb) architecture independent?

Tags: windows, typelib

Sorry about the lame question but reading MSDN did not make that clear to me.
Are type libraries (.tlb) independent with regard to architectures and versions of the Windows SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, type libraries should work across different cpu architectures.  This wouldn't have prevented a programmer from hammering a pointer or a handle into a integer, a not entirely uncommon sin since they are not types that are permitted in automation.  Such a component is unlikely to work well in 64-bit code.

Core automation types like BSTR and VARIANT declared in the Windows SDK headers are stable and can never be changed.  And haven't.